# Sum multiple columns based on references to multiple criteria - VBA not converting

Tags: excel, vba, filter

My code is `=SUMPRODUCT(H50:AA69*(H5:AA5=B10)*ISNUMBER(MATCH(F50:F69,K18:K24,0)))`

Where h50:aa69 is my data table and h5:aa5 is my row of years (b10 my criteria year that I would use to filter the data table, narrowing the selection to a single column). F50:F69 is a column of identifiers that my criteria range K18:K24 would further filter out rows from the single column.

My formula works in Excel. I tried translating it into VBA and I couldn't get it to work. Does anyone know why?

```
Sheet72.Range("C22") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((Sheet32. _
Range("h50:AA69")) * (Sheet32.Range("H5:AA5") = year) * _
Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
Match(Sheet32.Range("f50:f69"), Sheet72.Range("K18:K24"), 0)))
```

Comment: is `Sheet72.` supposed to be `Sheet32.`?

Comment: Your match() will cause a runtime error if it doesn't get a hit, so checking the return value with isnumber() will not work.

Comment: @scott craner no, it's correct as it is.

Comment: @tim williams what do you recommend? i wasn't sure of any other ways of checking a range with another range. Let me know if you have any suggestions

Comment: You can use the Worksheet.Evaluate() method to evaluate the existing formula which works on the worksheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams can you explain why that would work?

Comment: It would work because that's what Evaluate does - takes a worksheet formula and evaluates it in the context of the specific worksheet you call it on.  Array formulas are automatically treated as such.  You's need to update your worksheet formula to account for the different worksheet in your VBA though.  Just make sure to use `Sheet32.Evaluate()` and not Application.Evaluate (which defaults to evaluating the formula in the context of whatever sheet is active)

Answer (score 0):

What @Tim Williams meant (I think) is you need to trap the possibilty that   `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match` will fail because no match will be found at `Sheet72.Range("K18:K24")`, and it will retrun an error.

See the added `If` criteria in the code below:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheet32.Range("F50:F69"), Sheet72.Range("K18:K24"), 0)) Then
    Sheet72.Range("C22") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((Sheet32.Range("h50:AA69")) * _
    (Sheet32.Range("H5:AA5") = Year) * _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction. _
    Match(Sheet32.Range("f50:f69"), Sheet72.Range("K18:K24"), 0)))
Else
    MsgBox "Match failed"
End If
```